# Javascript form select option onchange remove last style

Tags: javascript, codeigniter

I am trying to mark a table that the user selected in a form, but if he changes it while he still in the same form selection, I want the last marking disappear and the new one showing. However, I've tried several approaches and this one is not working, it won't mark anything but if I call only the `select(x)`function it marks every single one I choose without removing the last one. I'll be glad for some help or ideas for improving my code.

View Code

```
 <select type="number" id="tnum2" name="num" style="display: none;" onchange="table_selection(this.value)">
                                <?php for ($i = 12; $i <= 23; $i++) : ?>
                                <option id="out" value="<?php echo $i; ?>"><?php echo $i; ?></option>
                            <?php endfor; ?></select>
```

JavaScript Code

```
function table_selection(x){
    remove_selection(),
    select(x);
}
function remove_selection(){
      for(var i=2;i<34;i++){
                document.getElementById(i).style.outline="none";
      }
}
function select(x){
      document.getElementById(x).style.outline="8px dotted #F2FF21";
}
```

Comment: Hey, I tried your code and it works fine(outlines the div with the same id as selected).You can share the image of the issue you seem to have at your end. If you want I can share the working snippet.

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null
    at remove_selection (tableMap.js:83)
    at table_selection (tableMap.js:90)
    at HTMLSelectElement.onchange (tableMap:157)

Comment: That's weird, it won't work for me. I attached the error above

Comment: I think this error might be because `<option>` only has values from 12 to 23, so when you try to remove elements with `id` from 2 to 34, some(most) of those elements don't exist.

Comment: oh okay, thank you for that!

Comment: Glad to be of help.